# Is there a plugin for calculating the walking time in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

In the previous QGIS version there's this plugin:
[Walking time](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/walkingtime/) but it's not compatible with QGIS 3. Is there another plugin doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Walking Time plugin compatible with QGIS 3 exists in Github, but not exist in QGIS Plugins Repository: https://github.com/SrNetoChan/WalkingTime

Download ZIP and extract to QGIS `plugins` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! However I get an error when trying to install.

"Couldn't load plugin 'walkingtime' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"

I'm using QGIS 3.16.0

Comment: @jeemil Search for the error. I don't get any error.